# Matching dashes in a URL regex

Tags: php, regex

I have used the following regex to get the urls from text (e.g. `"this is text http://url.com/blabla possibly some more text"`).

```
'@(https?://([-\w\.]+)+(:\d+)?(/([\w/_\.]*(\?\S+)?)?)?)@'
```

This works for all URLs but I just found out it doesn't work for URLs shortened like: `"blabla bla http://ff.im/-bEnA blabla"` becomes `http://ff.im/` after the match.

I suspect it has to do with the dash `-` after the slash `/`.

Answer (score 5):

Short answer: `[\w/_\.]` doesn't match `-` so make it `[-\w/_\.]`

Long answer:

```
@              - delimiter
(              - start of group
    https?://  - http:// or https://
    ([-\w.]+)+ - capture 1 or more hyphens, word characters or dots, 1 or more times.. this seems odd - don't know what the second + is for
    (:\d+)?    - optionally capture a : and some numbers (the port)
    (          - start of group
        /            - leading slash
        (            - start of group
            [\w/_\.] - any word character, underscore or dot - you need to add hyphen to this list or just make it [^?\S] - any char except ? or whitespace (the path + filename)
            (\?\S+)? - optionally capture a ? followed by anything except whitespace (the querystring)
        )?     - close group, make it optional
    )?         - close group, make it optional
)              - close group
@
```

Comment: Note that \w (letters + numbers) leaves out valid characters. RFC1738 says that "only alphanumerics, the special characters "$-_.+!*'(),", and reserved characters used for their reserved purposes may be used unencoded within a URL": i.e. just about anything can appear in a URL